# Define Infinity Limits

Tags: limits, analysis

- $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^-}f(x)=\infty,$ if for any $M>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $\left |f(x)\right |>M$ whenever $a-x<\delta$.
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^+}f(x)=\infty,$ if for any $M>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $\left |f(x)\right |>M$ whenever $x-a<\delta$.
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^-}f(x)=-\infty,$ if for any $M>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $\left |f(x)\right |<M$ whenever $a-x<\delta$.
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^+}f(x)=-\infty,$ if for any $M>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $\left |f(x)\right |<M$ whenever $x-a<\delta$.

**May you check these properties, if there is a false, may you write true?** Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are incorrect. The correct ones are:

- $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^-}f(x)=\infty,$ if for all $M>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)>M$ whenever $a-\delta<x<a$.
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^+}f(x)=\infty,$ if for all $M>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)>M$ whenever $a<x<a+\delta$.
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^-}f(x)=-\infty,$ if for all $M>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)<-M$ whenever $a-\delta<x<a$.
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^+}f(x)=-\infty,$ if for all $M>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)<-M$ whenever $a<x<a+\delta$.

Comment: Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to remove the absolute values everywhere. In the first two definitions you want $f(x)>M$, not $|f(x)|>M$. (because if the values of the function are negative the absolute value can also be very big). Also what you defined in the third and fourth definitions is that the limits are equal to zero. It should be $f(x)<-M$.

Comment: You forgot to mention that the inequalities with $\delta$ are also incorrect. For  example in the first limit. The inequality $a-x<\delta$ is equivalent with $x>a-\delta$. Now, that also allows for $x>a$ which does not necessarily have to satisfy the condition $f(x)>M$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The definitions are completely wrong.